# Explicity clearing the source resource after std::move

Tags: c++

Encountered this little piece of code in the wild:

```
class JetPlane
{
private:
  int engines;
  Seating *seating;
  string manufacturer;
public:
  JetPlane(JetPlane&& jetPlane)
  :engines(jetPlane.engines),seating(jetPlane.seating),manufacturer(std::move(jetPlane.manufacturer))
  {
    jetPlane.seating = nullptr;
    jetPlane.manufacturer.clear(); // Explicitly clearing a non-primitive type object.
  }
  JetPlane& operator=(JetPlane&& jetPlane)
  {
    if(this != &jetPlane){
      engines = jetPlane.engines;
      delete seating;
      seating = jetPlane.seating;
      jetPlane.seating = nullptr; 
      manufacturer = std::move(jetPlane.manufacturer);
      jetPlane.manufacturer.clear();  // Explicitly clearing a non-primitive type object.        
    }

  }
  //Other constructors/destructors
}
```

I am not sure about the objective of calling `jetPlane.manufacturer.clear();` in move constructors.
My guess is it has got something to do with resource management in the case where the argument to `jetPlane` is an `lvalue` which is wrapped in `std::move`. But then, I can't think about a solid use case here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: IMHO, it is not needed.  They could be doing it though since moving from a standard object leaves it in a valid but unspecified state.  Calling `clear` will leave it in a valid and specified state.

Comment: Not part of the question, but `delete jetPlane.seating;` in the move constructor is not right at least not in the combination with `seating(jetPlane.seating)`.

Comment: @sjsam Your move constructor also has a return type

Comment: I made those mistakes while typing. Rectified to match the original piece of code I saw. Thank you @t.niese and \@big-temp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the type of `manufacturer`. The standard guarantees that objects of standard library types after moved are left in an unspecified, but valid state. The exact type might need clear to be called to be reusable again. In theory, the moved from object could contain any garbage, as long as it is a valid state. The seem to attempt to workaround that.

Comment: @NathanOliver  Your comment to the question coupled with this answer makes sense. Thank you folks..